# Show Layered.jl canvas as a new window

Tags: graphics, window, julia, gtk, cairo

I know you can save the Canvas as a PNG/SVG/PDF in Layered.jl, but how would I display it in a new window. I know this is possible with Cairo (which is what Layered.jl is based on) and a Gtk Window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have alredy saved the original canvas as an svg or pdf file, you can then load it to another canvas such as `canvas = Canvas(300, 400)` with `draw_svg(canvas, "filename.svg")` or `draw_pdf(canvas, "filename.pdf")`. See the drawing.jl file in the Layered.jl distribution.